# aliyun oss image url is invalid in github issue but works in other markdown preview pages

Tags: github, markdown, open-source

all
i need to comment in github issue in markdown;
and there is an image url in my comment, which is a url from aliyun oss;
the markdown is like  this:

```
[缺陷描述]：

![](https://test-github-syncissue.oss-cn-wulanchabu.aliyuncs.com/obrobot/img1680232729512)

这是[一个超链接](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/zh/tutorial/path-params/)

带有颜色，那就红色吧
```

but github cannot display image from my url, and shows a blank

but this can work in other markdown website like https://1024tools.com/markdown

any one knows why???    Thanks~
and  this is the example link  above
https://github.com/ant-ob-hengtang/ekko/issues/18

macOs  and   chrome
image url is from aliyun oss

Comment: When I tried accessing your image, it showed me that the header was `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. And when github tried to load your image, it says `Non-Image content-type returned`. Maybe you should add `.png` to your filename?

Comment: You can also just upload a screenshot or a version of it in an image sharing app like https://imgur.com/, if you are allowed to do so (consider: copyright, corporate policies, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

i have figure this question
aliyun oss has default Content-Type which is application/octet-stream
so github cannot display picture directly
you should note the file Content-Type  or the file name suffix (like .png ...)
and then when you get the image url , this image will display as you expect.